# Filter bad word using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<div class = "filterW">
    <p class = "lineMsgAlign">
        <?php echo $rowSelectMsg['comment']; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Produce bad word filter code:

```
//select all bad wordfilter
$querySelectWordFilter = "SELECT * FROM badwordfilter";
$stmtSelectWordFilter = $conn->prepare($querySelectWordFilter);
$stmtSelectWordFilter->execute();

while($rowSelectWordFilter = $stmtSelectWordFilter->fetch()){
    $Array[] = $rowSelectWordFilter["filterWord"];
}

//filter word part
var filter = <?php echo json_encode($Array); ?>;
String.prototype.repeat = function(num){
    return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}

$('.filterW').text(function(i, txt){
    // Check all words in array
    for(var i=0; i<filter.length; i++){           
        var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'gi');

        // Create a new string filled with '*'
        var replacement = '*'.repeat(filter[i].length);
        txt = txt.replace(pattern, replacement);
    }
    return txt;
});
```

Question: The above code works properly, the problem is that it will filter my HTML code as well. However, I don't want to filter the HTML code. How can i prevent that?

For example (this is the result of the above code):

```
Enter user: I am **tester** sohai 

Result: I am tester *****
```

What I want is for the result to be like this:

```
Enter user: I am **tester** sohai 

Result: I am **tester** *****
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Interesting note with bad word filters is that they can have some undesired effects. Take the word "Assassin" for example. A sketchy bad word filter might change this to "Buttbuttin" (a personal favourite of mine). Just keep this in mind.

Comment: @Bono That's a great point to make.  This code happens to use the \b word boundary to make sure that it only matches on whole words.  The specific case that you mentioned wouldn't be possible, but that's not to say that there aren't edge cases lurking somewhere.  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the jQuery `text()` method, use the `html()` method.  The `text()` method removes all HTML markup from the element body, whereas the `html()` method returns the entire contents, including markup.

This code is an updated version of the javascript, which implements the word filter mechanism:

```
//filter word part
var filter = <?php echo json_encode($Array); ?>;
String.prototype.repeat = function(num) {
    return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}

$('.filterW').html(function(i, html) {
    // Check all words in array
    for (var i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'gi');
        // Create a new string filled with '*'
        var replacement = '*'.repeat(filter[i].length);
        html = html.replace(pattern, replacement);
    }
    return html;
});
```

This should work for your purposes, but there are at least 2 issues with this implementation.  The first is that the HTML markup will be effected if the word filter contains words that appear in the markup.  For instance, consider this example:

```
<a href="#" id="igloo">Igloo</a>
```

If you choose to filter for 'igloo', then both the body and id attribute of the link will be affected.  Depending on your needs, this might be acceptable.  If this is not acceptable, a full HTML parser is required to solve the problem.

The second issue is that words divided by markup will not be identified.  Consider this example:

```
<p>This is an exa<i>m</i>ple</p>
```

In this case, searching for 'example' will succeed when using the `text()` method, but will not when using the `html()` method.  It can be argued that markup embedded within a word indicates that the word is not actually a word, however, this is one of the approaches that spammers have historically used to bypass spam detection software.

Comment: wo ...thx you michael gaskill ..... Thank you a lot ^^ ....finally solve it Yeah~~~~